# How to prove that a union of a countably infinite set and a finite set is countably infinite with no intersection

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I can get my head around this thing...

So I can find examples of this using reals and naturals, but the intersection of reals and naturals is naturals.

Is there a way to prove that the union of a countably infinite and a finite set is countably infinite with no intersection? A working example maybe? these are some of the tricky questions I stumbled upon.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:**

- If $X$ is countably infinite, then there is a bijection $f : X \to \mathbb{N}$.
- If $Y$ is finite, then there is a bijection $g : Y \to \{0, 1, \ldots, |Y|-1\}$.
- Consider function $h : X \uplus Y \to \mathbb{N}$ defined as
  $$h(z) = \begin{cases}g(z) & \text{ for } z \in Y, \\ f(z) + |Y| & \text{ for } z \in X.\end{cases}$$

I hope this helps $\ddot\smile$